# How do I slow down boid particles without disturbing the speed of everything else in scene?

Tags: physics

I'm following this tutorial on how to slow down particles but I do not see the integration tab under physics like in the video. I noticed if I switched to a different physics type, it showed the integration tab but I need the boid physics type for my particular scene. How do I slow down the particles but keep everything else at a normal speed?

[Tutorial I'm following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W2AxbDLuTo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boids](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/boids.html) Physics for particle systems is controlled in the *Movement* sub panel of the *Physics* panel.  You can't set speeds, only ranges of influence, but if you want the boids to fly at most half as fast as they are now, you can change *Max Air Speed* to half the value you currently hae it set at.